# How to mock $rootScope method defined in controller?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

I'm writing unit tests for service and have a problem with *$rootScope.hideLogout();* method (see service code below), because it was defined in the controller and I don't have an access (at least I think so) to this controller from my tests, and I'm getting error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'hideLogout'

Here is my test:

```
it('should logout when player is in the system', function () {
        var user = {
            name: 'player name',
            password: 'password'
        };
        var userData = {
            access_token: 'token',
            token_type: 'bearer',
            expires_in: 1209599,
            userName: 'Player@maildomain.com',
            issued: "Fri, 12 Feb 2016 12:02:37 GMT",
            expires: 'Thu, 25 Feb 2016 13:22:45 GMT',
            userId: 2,
            accountType: 'Player',
            certifiedForAccess: true
        }
        localStorage.setItem('userAuth', JSON.stringify(user));
        localStorage.setItem('tokenKey', JSON.stringify(userData));
        localStorage.setItem('userId', userData.userId);

        authSvc.logOut(true, function() {}); // not sure about callback, so decided to put empty function for now
        var resultToken = localStorage.getItem('tokenKey');

        expect(localStorage.getItem('tokenKey')).toBeNull();
        expect(localStorage.getItem('userAuth')).toBeNull();
        expect(localStorage.getItem('userId')).toBeNull();
    });
```

My *beforeEach()* function:

```
beforeEach(function() {

    module('app');
    inject(function (_AuthService_, $q, $rootScope, $httpBackend, $state, _config_, _messages_) {
        scope = $rootScope;

        authSvc = _AuthService_;
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        config = _config_;
    });
});
```

Service method to be tested:

```
function logOut(logoutAnyway, cancelLogoutCallback) {
        if (logoutAnyway || !svc.isAdministrator()) {
            $rootScope.hideLogout(true);
            localStorage.removeItem(userIdKey);
            localStorage.removeItem(userAuthKey);
            localStorage.removeItem(tokenKey);
            $state.go('login');
            svc.fakeUserId = null;
        } else {
            $rootScope.showLogout(cancelLogoutCallback);
        }
    }
```

Could you point me to some direction about what to do with it?

Comment: Putting functions on $rootScope is a BAD idea. If those utility functions change the page view, put them into a directive. Otherwise, put them into a service.

Comment: @MBielski I can't change code, i'm not a developer, just a tester. But I'll ask a developer if we can change it. Is there any way to avoid code changing and test it as is?

Comment: Your developer should know better than to use $rootScope like that. Push hard for a change. It it untestable and unmaintainable as is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `scope = $rootScope.new()` in your test.

**UPDATE**

You also need to use `spyOn` by Jasmine on the methods.

```
spyOn(scope , 'hideLogout');
spyOn(scope , 'showLogout');
```

**UPDATE 2**

After `scope = $rootScope.new()` try mocking the two methods which are on the `$rootScope`

```
scope.hideLogout = function () {};
scope.showLogout = function () {};
```

Then add the `spyOn` part of the code

Comment: I've already tried, put this _spyOn_ lines into _beforeEach()_, but it doesn't see this methods: "method hideLogout() doesn't exist". Same when I put it into test itself.

Comment: stil no progress :( placed functions as you said, tried `spyOn` with and without `.and.callThrough()` but test runner says that _Object doesn't support property or method 'hideLogout()'_